# Setting Danish Character Text

Tags: android, string, text, json

I am getting some strings from json. My string contains special characters like "æ" from Næstved an many more like "ø" from køkken. But When I set Text these strings to ant textview, I get my strings printed in unusual way.

**Example: For køkken I get k&oslash ;kken.**

I think I need to encode or decode my string somewhere but where I don,t know.

Please help.
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed version of your string represents an HTML encoded entity. You might want to verify that it is not coming in this way in your JSON data, but in any case, to decode it you can use the [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) method from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
final String escaped = "k&oslash;kken";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(escaped));
```

Output:

```
køkken
```

Comment: Does i need to add some package to use this StringEscapeUtils... because my project saying to create class.

Comment: You need to include the Apache Commons Lang library in your project. I included a link to it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the Latin Coding for your characters? I know the Ash character can be coded with æ and will show up æ in the browser.

Here is the [a list of codes](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

Hope this helps!